# Cannot move check box to align with my bootstrap textbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle for code, then screenshot of what I see on my screen, since JSFiddle is displaying it wrong :

(entire code in link, brief view below)
   http://jsfiddle.net/WeDLR/1/
   [image: pic1]

```
        <div class="col-lg-3"> 
            <form method =post action="/UnitInfo/TSMServlet" NAME="form01">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="terminalname" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Terminal Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" display="inline-block" name="checkbox_tname" onclick="checkbox_tname_click();">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tname" placeholder="Terminal Name">
                        </div> 
                </div>
        </div>
```

Currently, my check box is partially under my textbox. I want to make it so the center of the check box is on the same line as the center of the text box. How can I do this?

PS. If I don't use a bootstrap textbox, it seems like my alignment is just fine.

Comment: 1. we need your css
2. your html is not right
3. I don't see anything with class "checkbox"

Comment: When I use label class checkbox, it doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

Comment: If you want to target checkbox, you should use input[type=checkbox] {...} or give a class "checkbox" to that input. Try doing input {float:left} or input {display: inline-block} and then move it.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms There are examples of inline forms and horizontal forms, that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try following css...

```
.checkbox {
    width: 100%;
}
.form-group {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline
}
.form-control {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WeDLR/)

Comment: Yeah this doesn't quite seem to work for me. I think it has something to do with some other CSS I may have. Is there a way for me to manually move the checkbox?

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle. This is exactly what I have, but it still doesn't align correctly http://jsfiddle.net/WeDLR/1/

Comment: All you did was change the CSS? It still ain't working for me, let me try something else too

Comment: I have just changed css for checkbox...checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Man, I think it has to do something with the table underneath it. Because I don't see any other reason why this isn't working. Here's the entire code here. If you can help me, I would greatly appreciate it. If you can't, I understand too. http://www.pastebin.ca/2467657

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if its ok I will explain. I did not change any css. See Fiddle.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<font class="header">
<center>
  <b>Unit Information Filter </b>
</center>
</font><br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-3">
<form method="post" action="/UnitInfo/TSMServlet" NAME="form01">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="terminalname" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 control-label">Terminal Name</label>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-lg-2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox_tname" onclick="checkbox_tname_click();">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tname" placeholder="Terminal Name">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="tbid" class="col-lg-2 control-label">TBID</label>
 <div class="col-lg-10">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tbid" placeholder="TBID">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="version" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Version</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="version" placeholder="Version">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="lastconnect" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Connect Time</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="from" class="col-lg-2 control-label">From </label>
 <div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="timefrom" placeholder="FROMdate">
<label for="to" class="control-label">To</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="timeto" placeholder="TOdate">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ONCLICK="checkValue();" value="search" CLASS="BTN_MENU" >
Submit
   </button>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B5T3t/4/)